# How do I run a separate version of jquery in shopify for my flexslider plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery, shopify, flexslider

I have a flexslider pano on my index page, to get it work properly I have to use 'jQuery' version '1.6.2-1.7.2'. If I change the version to `1.7.3` or higher, the slider has a glitchy animation.  The problem is that I have a drop down menu that only functions using versions `1.7.3` or higher in the same page.

I am trying to figure out how to make flexslider run on version `1.7.2` or lower, without affecting the rest of the site.

Here's the script for the flexslider:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
  $(window).load(function() {
  $('.flexslider').flexslider({
    animation: "fade",
    animationLoop: true,
    controlNav: false
  });
});
</script>
```

I took some suggestions on overflow but they don't seem to work on `Shopify`.
Such as using `jQuery.noConflict()`;

Here's my version:

```
 <script type='text/javascript' src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>  

<script type='text/javascript'>  

 var $jq = jQuery.noConflict();  

</script>  

<script type='text/javascript' src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.3/jquery.min.js"></script>  


<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
  $j(window).load(function() {
  $j('.flexslider').flexslider({
    animation: "fade",
    animationLoop: true,
    controlNav: false
  });
});
</script>
```

The website is `enrou.co`, I currently disabled the `jQuery` so you can see that the pano is glitchy when you switch between images. The only way for me to disable the animations is to run `jQuery` version `1.7.2` or earlier, but that disables the functionality of other plugins.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I use multiple versions of jQuery on the same page?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1566595/can-i-use-multiple-versions-of-jquery-on-the-same-page)

Comment: I tried the answers from there and I think shopify might be different because they didn't work.